# adding custom filter on Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct getLoadedProductCollection not working

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, magento2.3, filter, product-collection

I am overriding below product collection function with sku filter but its giving all results in category page including that sku product.

```
    /**
     * Retrieve loaded category collection
     *
     * @return AbstractCollection
     */
    public function getLoadedProductCollection()
    {
          $collection = $this->_getProductCollection();
          $collection->addAttributeToFilter('sku', 'test');
          return $collection;
    }
```

Comment: First of all, please check it $this->_getProductCollection(); return null or not. I think it return null.

Comment: @RohanHapani it is displaying data when i print it using  $collection->getData()

Comment: Oh..!! Then, MuhammadHasam answer is right. It should be working.

Comment: @RohanHapani i have tried MuhammadHasam answer its not working

Answer (score 1):

> Try below code `->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('like' => '%24-MB01%'))`

```
public function getLoadedProductCollection()
{
      $collection = $this->_getProductCollection()
                         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                         ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', 
                            array('like' => '%24-MB01%'))
                         ->load();
}
```

Comment: I have done same but not working

Comment: check updated answer.

Comment: Yes Mohit not working above code can you check your side ?

Comment: can you try like this `->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('eq' => '24-MB01'));`

Comment: No working Mohit

Comment: try like this `->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('like' => '%24-MB01%'))`

Comment: refer this link for more https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158462/get-product-collection-based-on-custom-attribute-drop-down-attribute-value?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Use this code, I think you have to dispatch after collection filter

```
public function getLoadedProductCollection()
{

    $collection = $this->_getProductCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('sku', 'test');
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
        'catalog_block_product_list_collection',
        ['collection' => $collection]
    );

    return $collection;
}
```

I hope this will help, though I don't test my code

Comment: its not working

Comment: Are you sure, you are overriding `getLoadedProductCollection()` function rightly?

Comment: I am even adding this directly in core file yet for sure